# React Native load multiple SVG image

Tags: react-native, svg, sti

For a project in react native, I need to display a lot of SVG images.
I'm able to import my files as component and display it in my view this way:

```
import Logo from './assets/interface/logo.svg';

<Logo
 width={200}
 height={200}
/>
```

But I can't write it by hand for every image.
That why I tried to use SvgUri of [react-native-svg](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-svg) for local files.

```
import SvgUri from 'expo';

<SvgUri
  width="200"
  height="200"
  source={{
    uri: './assets/interface/logo.svg'
  }}
/>
```

But I've got stuck with an [invariant violation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mysmx.jpg).
After some research, comments and text in the SVG file can lead to this kind of errors but after removing comments and other stuff I still have the same error.

Is there a way in react native to display a lot of SVG files without having to write 300 import by hand ?

**Update 1:**

```
require('./assets/interface/logo.svg')
```

Still give me the same error.

Comment: you may need to use `require('./asset/interface/logo.svg')` to make it work

Comment: Just tried but I sadly get the same error. (will update the post)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or you could customize [this](https://github.com/murtraja/react-native-svg-icon-generator) python script to do the job for you

*Disclaimer:* I am the author of the svg-icon-generator

Comment: I'm finally using your solution. It's sad to loose the svg power but since I have more than 600 pictures, the icon creation was annoying. Maybe keeping the original name of the picture and adding multiple picture transformation will be a good idea. But thanks you for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I finally manage to turn around.
I used [icomoon.io](https://icomoon.io) to make icons with my every svg I have.
And then used [react-native-vector-icons](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons) to load them as icon.
If someone ever found a better solution, I'm really interested.

1. Install :
   npm install react-native-vector-icons --save
2. Create your icons: [icomoon.io](https://icomoon.io)
3. Place the *selection.json* and your *font.ttf* in your project
4. Load the Font:

Code :

```
import icoMoonConfig from './assets/fonts/selection.json';
const Icon = createIconSetFromIcoMoon( icoMoonConfig );
```

5. Import and use your SVG

Code :

```
import icoMoonConfig from './assets/fonts/selection.json';
const Icon = createIconSetFromIcoMoon( icoMoonConfig );

<Icon name="logo" size={130} color="#000"/>
```

Comment: oh yes indeed you can create a font my bad didn't understand your problem well enough yes vector icon is the best ;)

Comment: what is selection.json?

Comment: If I remember well it's a json file generated by icomoon.